# Why php slim headers are already concatenated?

Tags: java, php, header, httpurlconnection, slim

I need to put some headers in a `HttpUrlConnection`, in order to send them to a web server written in PHP using the Slim framework (version 3).

I have troubles when I put more headers with the same key in the connection.
For example:

```
HttpUrlConnection conn = createConnectionSomeHow();
conn.addRequestProperty("myHeader", "value1");
conn.addRequestProperty("myHeader", "value2");
```

If I use a *watch* on `conn.getRequestProperties()`, I see a single header with the key `"myHeader"` and a list of 2 elements as value. Just as I want.

But my web server is not receiving well that header.

If I write:

```
$values = $request->getHeader('myHeader');
```

`$values` is not a list of 2 elements, it's a list of 1 element with value `"value1, value2"`, that is, the 2 values concatenated in a single string.
This is really weird. I read from the [Slim documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/request.html#the-request-headers):

> You can get a single header’s value(s) with the PSR 7 Request object’s
>   getHeader($name) method. This returns **an array of values** for the given
>   header name. Remember, a single HTTP header may have more than one
>   value!

There is a method that concatenates the header's values automatically, and it is called `getHeaderLine`. And I'm not calling it. I am calling `getHeader`.

Is this behavior correct? Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: What is HttpUrlConnection?  What's in $_SERVER for this header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch. This is actually a bug.

I've created an [issue at the Slim Github project](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/2163) for this.

As workaround you could split the header by yourself:

```
$values = explode(',', $request->getHeaderLine('myHeader'));
```

Comment: Not a bug. Slim\Http's handling of this is the same as Zend\Diactoros.